# How to use gitlab without hostname

Tags: gitlab

I'm using gitlab within my company network. We don't have any internal DNS set up to allow me to use internal hostnames - all access to servers is via IP only.

I used the omnibus installer to install gitlab on a dedicated VM.

Currently I'm having to set the hosts files on my client machines to point to the IP address of the gitlab server. Is there a way to just use the IP address of the machine for gitlab?

I've tried to set it up using the IP address as external_url in gitlab.yml but no gitlab pages are served when I visit it using the IP, and I'm unable to check out any git repos using the IP.

Is it possible? If so, what settings do I need to look at?

Answer (score 1):

If you have set up the client's hosts file anyway, then why stick to the IP?

If you don't have an internal DNS, get one. They're cool. As your use case seems to be managing internal names only without connection to the outside world, using a DNS proxy like `dnsmasq` would suit your needs, and it's fairly easy to set up.

Managing your client's hosts file with SCCM or Puppet might be an option too.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I don't manage all of the (potential) client machines as we're also using external developers. At the moment they're not using git but the plan is to move our existing svn repos to git so I need a simple way to allow them to connect.

Changing config only on the single machine that is causing this seemed the obvious answer, rather than making network wide changes or forcing external developers to change their setup.

Comment: You do need to put forth more information about the potential clients (developers) and how they fit in your network, about how the gitlab box is accessible, and about how the gitlab's webserver is configured for us to provide a helpful answer.